# query dynamodb map field

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries

I'm unable to filter dynamodb map in AWS console

[image]

Querying with mapper contains "A" works. structure of mapper is

```
"mapper": [
    "\"A\"",
    "\"B\"",
    {
      "bar": "foo"
    }
  ]
```

How can I filter {"bar":"foo"}.

I tried

- contains {"bar":"foo"}
- contains '{"bar":"foo"}'
- contains {bar:foo}

**But none works**. Please suggest.

Comment: Try `mapper.bar`

Comment: mapper.bar -  contains - "foo" ; mapper.bar - = - "foo"; neither worked.

Answer (score 0):

If the `mapper` list is reliably ordered, the console's PartiQL editor can filter records containing `{"bar": "foo"}` at index 2:

```sql
select * from myTable where mapper[2].bar = 'foo'
```

Note:  This is technically a `scan` operation. You can make it a `query` by adding `WHERE` conditions for your primary key.